# Transparent FavIcon in chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

First: I like the new design! It is great.

One minor detail is the FavIcon color and its transparency. In my list of tabs and bookmarks it is dull and doesn't stand out. (I'm using Chrome here)

In my Favorites tools bar: You can hardly see the S and the hexgon-lines are almost invisible, only some colored dots remain.

[image]

As active and inactive tab:

[image: FavIcon in active and inactive tabs]

**Twitter**

Even as Twitter icon it is 'white', 'blank':

[image]

Compare it with other SE icons:

[image]

**More general**

It's probably the overall look-and-feel of the logo, great idea, but lacking 'power' (like the tipping beeker, the StackOverflow logo, the English logo, the Gaming logo) See [this list](http://stackexchange.com/sites), almost all logos have strong colors and stand out as icon.

Comment: I agree! I'm going to re-tool the favicons this week. I may give it a dark background so the logo pops out more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: SPSE twitter icon]

The [twitter logo](http://twitter.com/#!/stacksharepoint) has been updated. I'll be uploading site favicons with a darker bg this afternoon.