# SharePoint site icon background on Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion, bug

I am aware of this questions: [Transparent FavIcon in chrome](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/transparent-favicon-in-chrome)

It does not solve the issue.

On this site the icon for the SharePoint.stackexchange.com appears with a black background. For example on my profile page

[image]

But on other sites in the Stack Exchange network the black background of the icon is not showing and the icon is hard to recognize. Here is the icon in my profile on StackOverflow

[image]

I don't know what exactly is going on there, but I feel it is a bug. The SharePoint site icon is hardly distinguishable on any other Stack Exchange sites. The black background that helps identify the icon is not visible in other SE sites.

Any ideas?

Edit: on the SuperUser site, the SharePoint site icon shows correctly with a black background. 
[image]

How come the icon does not show consistently across all sites in the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: +1 It anonys me too!

Comment: @BennySkogberg - let's take the opportunity to change that logo. I propose [this one](http://blog.liquidmercurysolutions.com/Portals/156196/images/SP%20Unicorn.png)

Comment: Uhmm -- maybe not quite that one. If you have pre-teen daughters who like purple and pink, I'm sure they'll love it. I'd be happy with the SharePoint Hex-(or whatever something-)a-gon on the black background throughout the Stack network.

Comment: Ok, we will use the Hex on the 1 April and the pony the rest of the year. And don't go telling me you wanted the opposite.

Comment: Should we ask this one on http://meta.stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is just a caching issue, or maybe the image was changed between the time you posted your question and when I checked just now? When I view your account over on Stack Overflow the SharePoint icon has a black background for me:

[image: Screenshot of user profile accounts listing on Stack Overflow]

Clicking through the "Accounts" link on Stack Overflow and being sent to [your full list of accounts](http://stackexchange.com/users/201495/teylyn?tab=accounts) on stackexchange.com I did see that they're still using the icon with white background:

[image: Screenshot of SharePoint SE icon in the Stack Exchange full user accounts listing]

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post this on Meta.StackExchange but I found out that it has been changed on all my other SE-acount sites. Can you confirm that this issue have been solved to you as well?

Site Icons on UX.SE:

[image]

Comment: yes, the icon has been consistently black for a while now.